# Not Understanding what im doing wrong(beginning)

Tags: python-3.x, list, input

The Problem: Write a function that takes a list of numbers, numbers, and returns the largest number in the list. If there are no numbers in the list, return 0

As I understand it;  I need to define a list, take user input, place the input into my list, place a max function to identity my list's largest number, and end with an if statement based on if there are numbers or not

code:

```
n = []
def BG(n):
    numbers = int(input("type numbers:"))
    n.append(numbers)
    largest = max(n)
    if numbers in n:
        return n
    else:
        return "0"    
    return n
BG(n)
```

*please assist

wrote out my logic but was completely stumped and lacking understanding

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is that you try to convert the whole list to int not any single number.

```
def BG():
    try:
        all_numbers_as_one_string = input("type numbers:") # read the numbers
        array_of_strings_representing_numbers = all_numbers_as_one_string.split(" ")
        numbers_array = map(int, array_of_strings_representing_numbers)
        largest_number = max(numbers_array)
        return largest_number
    except: # if something goes wrong (there are no numbers or one of the inputs is not parsable to int)
        return 0
print("Largest number is: " + str(BG()))
```

Some tests:

```
python3 x.py
type numbers:1 2 3
Largest number is: 3

python3 x.py
type numbers:
Largest number is: 0

python3 x.py
type numbers: 1 hello world 2
Largest number is: 0
```